# crossed arrows in \xymatrix

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic, xymatrix

I would like to strike out arrows in \xymatrix. Here is what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ ABCDE\ar@{<->} |*@{x} [r]^<<<<<<<<{\text{label}}_<<<<<<<<{\text{label}} \ar[d]& F \ar[r] \ar[d]& G\ar[rr]\ar[d] && H\ar[d]\\
 ABCDEFGH\ar@{<->} |*@{x} [r] \ar[d]& II \ar[r] \ar[d]& JJ\ar[rr]^{\text{very long label}} \ar[d] && KK\ar[d]\\
 ABCD\ar [r] & EEE \ar[r] & FFF\ar[rr] && GGG
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the cross in the arrows connecting ABCDE with F and ABCDEFGH with II is not in the middle of the arrow which doesn't look very good. How can this be fixed?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you asked for an `xy` solution, but maybe it's worth switching over to `tikz-cd`.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1cm]
  ABCDE\arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\times"{anchor=center},"\text{label}","\text{label}"{below}]\arrow[d] & F\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & G\arrow[rr]\arrow[d] && H\arrow[d]\\
  ABCDEFGH\arrow[r, leftrightarrow, "\times"{anchor=center}]\arrow[d] & II\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & JJ\arrow[rr,"\text{very long label}"]\arrow[d] && KK\arrow[d]\\
  ABCD\arrow[r] & EEE\arrow[r] & FFF\arrow[rr] && GGG
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```